# I am new to discrete math and am having trouble proving this:

Tags: discrete-mathematics, proof-writing

Prove that $n^4 - n^2$ is even for all $n$ in the set of all natural number

Comment: An informal argument would be to observe that $n^4$ and $n^2$ takes after the parity of $n$. i.e. If $n$ is even (or odd) then so is $n^4$ and $n^2$. Now what do you get when you subtract any 2 odd or even numbers?

Answer (score 5):

$1)$ If $n$ is even then $n^4$ and $n^2$ are even and then the difference is even;

$2)$ If $n$ is odd then $n^4$ and $n^2$ are odd and then the difference is even;

Answer (score 4):

$n^4-n^2=n^2(n^2-1)=n^2(n-1)(n+1)$, and exactly one of $n$ and $n+1$ is even.

Comment: Isn't it enough to stop at $n^2(n^2-1)$?

Comment: @carmichael561 $n^2-1$ and $n^2$ are consecutive numbers, so it is obvious that exactly one must be even, so no, there is no need to factor $n^2-1$ in this case. For proving divisibility by $3$, the further factorization is useful.

Answer (score 0):

HINT: use that $$n^4-n^2=n^2(n^2-1)=(n-1)n^2(n+1)$$ if $$n$$ is odd then $$n+1$$ is even, if $n$ is even then $$n^2$$ is also even

Answer (score 0):

Use induction: $n=0$ yields $0^4-0^2=0-0=0\equiv 0\pmod 2$.

Assume true for $n$, i.e. $n^4-n^2\equiv 0\pmod 2$.

We need to prove it is true for $n+1$, i.e. we need to prove $(n+1)^4-(n+1)^2\equiv0\mod 2$.

Expanding we get:

$$n^4+4n^3+6n^2+4n+1-n^2-2n-1\\=(n^4-n^2) + 4n^3 + 6n^2 + 2n=\\(n^4-n^2)+2(2n^3+3n^2+n)\equiv 0\pmod 2$$.

Comment: Correct, but overkill unless the point is to practice induction. The several simple parity arguments in other answers are much more appropriate.